# querying up a record variable number

Tags: sql-server

MY TABLE;

```
  ID- PRODUCT - PIECES
  1 - BANANA  -   2
  2 - APPLE   -   3
  3 - ORANGE  -   1
  4 - PEACH   -   2
  5 - CHERRY  -   2
  6 - STRAWBERRY- 4
```

I WANT THIS RESULTS;

```
  ID- PRODUCT - PIECES
  1 - BANANA  -   2
  1 - BANANA  -   2
  2 - APPLE   -   3
  2 - APPLE   -   3
  2 - APPLE   -   3
  3 - ORANGE  -   1
  4 - PEACH   -   2
  4 - PEACH   -   2
  5 - CHERRY  -   2
  5 - CHERRY  -   2
  6 - STRAWBERRY- 4
  6 - STRAWBERRY- 4
  6 - STRAWBERRY- 4
  6 - STRAWBERRY- 4
```

How can i?

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING what you want at us? If you want something, what's stopping you? What have *you* tried to solve the problem and why didn't it work? If you haven't made an attempt, why not? What research did you perform, and what about it did you not understand or fail to implement? Please don't make demands of the volunteers here to do it for you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They are not the same thing.  Note that SQL is not a very good data generation tool.  It might be easier to do this outside of your database.

Comment: *"How can i?"* In SQL Server, I would use a Tally. ***If*** the numbers are going to remain low (i.e. 10 or less in my opinion) an rCTE would also be a candidate, but the performance will dip quickly once you get to larger values for `PIECES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 1 AS level FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 3 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 4 FROM yourTable
    -- add more queries for higher levels
)

SELECT
    ID,
    PRODUCT,
    PIECES
FROM cte
WHERE
    PIECES >= level
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

In SQL Server or MySQL 8+ we could use a recursive CTE instead of the hard-coded version above, to handle an arbitrary number of record duplications.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer,but max pieces is changeable, can I make this query dynamic? Or how can i ?

Comment: First, tell us which database _and_ version you are using.  To extend my answer on either database, you could just add more queries to union with higher levels.  See the answer by @larnu for a recursive CTE option on SQL Server.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: That isn't a database @YunusEmreDECECI, it's an application. You can get the version with `PRINT @@VERSION;`

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming*** SQL Server.

rCTE:

```
--Sample data
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'BANANA',2),
                (2,'APPLE',3),
                (3,'ORANGE',1),
                (4,'PEACH',2),
                (5,'CHERRY',2),
                (6,'STRAWBERRY',4))V(ID, Product,Pieces)),
--solution
rCTE AS(
    SELECT V.ID,
           V.Product,
           V.Pieces,
           1 AS Piece
    FROM VTE V
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.ID,
           r.Product,
           r.Pieces,
           r.Piece +1
    FROM VTE V
         JOIN rCTE r ON V.ID = r.ID
                    AND V.Pieces > r.Piece)
SELECT ID,
       Product,
       Pieces
FROM rCTE
ORDER BY ID, Piece;
```

Tally:

```
--Sample data
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1,'BANANA',2),
                (2,'APPLE',3),
                (3,'ORANGE',1),
                (4,'PEACH',2),
                (5,'CHERRY',2),
                (6,'STRAWBERRY',4))V(ID, Product,Pieces)),
N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(Pieces) FROM VTE)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2) --100 rows, Add more as needed
SELECT V.ID,
       V.Product,
       V.Pieces
FROM VTE V
     JOIN Tally T ON V.Pieces >= T.I
ORDER BY V.ID,
         T.I;
```

As mentioned in the comment, I recommend the tally, especially if `PIECES` will have much larger values.

Comment: Thank you ,it's solve my problem.

Comment: You're welcome @YunusEmreDEVECİ, please do accept the answer as the solution if so. You get reputation points for it (really important as a new Contributer) and future users know the answer was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It's okey,i am new here

Answer (score 0):

From [Here](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/repeat-rows-according-to-column-value.aspx),

Create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION NumbersTable (
  @fromNumber int,
  @toNumber int,
  @byStep int
)
RETURNS @NumbersTable TABLE (i int)
AS
BEGIN

  WITH CTE_NumbersTable AS (

    SELECT @fromNumber AS i

    UNION ALL

    SELECT i + @byStep
    FROM CTE_NumbersTable
    WHERE
      (i + @byStep) <= @toNumber
  )
  INSERT INTO @NumbersTable
  SELECT i FROM CTE_NumbersTable OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

  RETURN;
END
```

And Use ***CrossApply***,

```
create table #tab(Id int,PRODUCT varchar(200), PIECES int);

insert into #tab VALUES(1,'BANANA',2),
                (2,'APPLE',3),
                (3,'ORANGE',1),
                (4,'PEACH',2),
                (5,'CHERRY',2),
                (6,'STRAWBERRY',4)

create table #tab2(Id int,PRODUCT varchar(200), PIECES int);
INSERT INTO #tab2(Id, PRODUCT,PIECES)
SELECT Id, PRODUCT,PIECES
FROM #tab t1
CROSS APPLY dbo.NumbersTable(1,t1.PIECES,1)

select * from #tab2
```

Comment: Why use a multi-line table-value function here? They are vastly slower than inline TVFs.